# Encrypting password or workaround

Tags: powershell

I am bit of a lazy guy, so I have created a script that opens many applications for me. Works fine as ISE opened with Administrator credentials, also opens apps with admin creds, however some of them need a different credentials.

Is it possible, to make powershell remember typed in password each time I log in and open it? (I know that variables are stored only till ps is opened)

Thing is - I cannot store a visible password in profile/text file or in a script, as this is a jump server used by many people. Is it somehow possible to type a password once, make PS encrypt it and each time I will open PS, it will decrypt it and use? or any workaround possible around this?

edit with code:

It's the only part I would like to change

```
$currentPW = "some password"
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("domain\username",$CurrentPW)
start "c:\application.exe" -credential $credentials
```

It kinda works but it would require me, to input  the password everytime I log in to device, so I could go for option like:

```
$currentPW = read-host "Provide your password"
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("domain\username",$CurrentPW)

start "c:\application.exe" -credential $credentials
```

but this would require me to input the password each time I log in to system and open PS as it does not remember variables after restart.
So...is it even possible to make this work?^^

Comment: Is the jump server being used with shared an account?

Comment: Do the passwords need to be in plain-text for the applications, or can you use a secure-string? It's best to include your code with questions, replacing confidential info like usernames/passwords with example values. When you do this we can provide a better answer that's relevant to you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ConvertTo-SecureString` to encrypt the password using the users account key, then save this secure string to a file to load at a later time.

This assumes you are the only one with access to the logon account (not an account with shared credentials), as anyone who can logon as the account can decrypt the file.

```
$username = "domain\username"
$passwordFile = "C:\folder\EncryptedPassword.txt"

#if password file exists: populate $securePwd from file contents
If (Test-Path $passwordFile) {
    $pwdTxt = Get-Content $passwordFile
    $securePwd = $pwdTxt | ConvertTo-SecureString
}
#if no file: prompt for password, create file and populate $securePwd
Else {
    $password = Read-Host "Provide your password"
    $securePwd = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 
    $securePwd | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content $passwordFile
}

$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $securePwd

Start-Process "c:\application.exe" -Credential $credentials
```

Comment: I might did not get something, or you made a small mistake, but you have provided 2 different file paths, which was not working for me.
I have changed it to be the same file in both, which made script to populate and ask the same file for encrypted password. However I have created a simple switch,
that asks me did I change the password. If yes, it is asking for new one, and populates it encrypted to the file.

Thanks a lot as this script after small twerking, works perfect: )

Comment: Ah yes, fixed that now! Butchered an existing script for the answer and missed one bit :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have PowerShell 3.0 or newer, you can also combine `Get-Credential` with `Export-CliXml` to export a `PSCredential` object as an XML file. Example:

```
Get-Credential | Export-CliXml "C:\XML Files\credential.xml"
```

You can then import the credentials using `Import-CliXml`. Example:

```
$credential = Import-CliXml "C:\Xml Files\credential.xml"
```

Note that the password is encrypted using DPAPI, so you can only import the credentials using `Import-CliXml` on the same computer using the same user account that was used to export the credentials using `Export-CliXml`.